# Typescript not working when wrapping myFunctionSignature inside another function

Tags: typescript

Do you understand why the following TS is not throwing (see comments in the snippet)?

[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgA5ynAtgZ2QbwChlkMBzADQH4AuZHMKUM40qMgTVvsedfIBa3BkxAsAvoUKhIsRCiwBPAGIBXEAjDAA9iADKwMiDhhVUFERLpMubtew5Ckwgl0N62rBDUatu5AC8yAAU%20Pa44nRKPpo6%20obGpuYAlIEAfASsriA42gA2EAB0edpkweE4yU5SuV4xfiChFXT45BR0AOSQDB3i4qkkg0PDI6PDAPTjyMBgyADu2lAA1jgANMjaSwCEhLXe6rG6TRgOLXsAkhqL5poAguyqXuCd3WC9-WNjk9OzACbaEBwIC680WS3Wmx2e3qcWONhwLTaL0Bb3WFyuUBuYHuZEeEGeyC6KPeA2%20M2Q-0BwNmC2WEO2Umy7hgACZAiE9gAFE64M6eCCXVyYiB3B5PMDInofAIZSweOoHBpw07yiDc%20EfT5a7VDMl-AFAkG08EbJZOZCMtyzGAAZnZwS5PIRBCRhNeHTR-MF1xF2LF%20IlbuJ0tlrGhithYSddEdGoGOoToz1oOWa2QACNVLNyTgABbaVR5X7IEDaMDrOa5xRUHbiIA)

```js
interface params {
  argX?: string
  argY?: string
  argZ?: string
}

interface myFunctionSignature {
  params?: params
}

const someFunction = ({params}: myFunctionSignature) => {
  console.log(params)
}

someFunction({params: {argX: 'test'}})                                 // it works, ok!
someFunction({params: {someIncorrectArgument: 'test'}})                // it doesn't work, ok!
someFunction({params: {argX: 'test', someIncorrectArgument: 'test'}})  // it doesn't work, ok!

const f2 = (someParams: {someIncorrectArgument: 'test'}) => {
  someFunction({params: someParams})                                   // it doesn't work, ok
} 

const f3 = (someParams: {argX: 'test', someIncorrectArgument: 'test'}) => {
  someFunction({params: someParams})                                  // it works, but it should not, why?!
}
```

Comment: the parameter in f3 is assignable to `params`. [Excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are only done with literals. For others, it's allowed to have extra properties in the object. Really shouldn't matter, since TS will stop you from trying to access `params.someIncorrectArgument` which means it's irrelevant whether that one exists or not. And I suggest not just doing something with all properties at once - it's more likely to be wrong than right.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this discrepancy is because TypeScript handles assignment for object literals a bit differently to other values.

Normally, TypeScript is 'structurally typed'. That means, type `A` can be assigned to variable `B` so long as type `A` has *at least* all the same properties with the same types - so considering the following types

```
interface Foo {
  a: string
  b: string
}

interface Bar {
  a: string
  b: string
  c: string
}

declare let first: Foo
declare let second: Bar
```

This does not result in an error

```
first = second
```

Whereas this does

```
second = first
```

When dealing with object literals however, the compiler does something called [exhaustiveness checking](https://dev.to/babak/exhaustive-type-checking-with-typescript-4l3f), which means it will produce an error if the literal has any extra properties not declared in the original type. So that means that this *will* produce an error

```
foo = {
  a: 'one',
  b: 'two',
  c: 'three'
}
```

So taking from your examples:

```
someFunction({params: {argX: 'test', someIncorrectArgument: 'test'}})  // it doesn't work, ok!
```

This doesn't work because you are supplying `params` as an object literal, so exhaustiveness checking applies.

```
const f3 = (someParams: {argX: 'test', someIncorrectArgument: 'test'}) => {
  someFunction({params: someParams})                                  // it works, but it should not, why?!
}
```

This however *does* work because `someParams` is now an *argument* with a typed defined in the function signature (the type being `{argX: 'test', someIncorrectArgument: 'test'}`), rather than an object literal - which means that exhaustiveness checking is *not* applied.